# Generate tables from values of one column

Tags: sql, postgresql

New to SQL , I have a table  called  `DataSetFact` with a column called `data`

| data |
| --- |
| SOCIETE;SSY;Societe SSY |
| SOCIETE;XXX ;Societe XXX |
| ETABLISSEMENT;SITE_AV;Aveyron;AAT;SITE_AV |
| DEPOT;FRCAN ;ENTREPOT FOURNISSEUR FRCAN |
| GRP;APPMESURE;SUIVI APPAREILS DE MESURE |
| ARTICLE;59000013;REFERENCE Jumbo;MATPREMFAB;Article |
| ARTICLE;59000015;REFERENCE Jumbo222;MATPREMFAB222;Article |

I want from the column `data` create  5 tables & Columns base on `;` seperator

Table names are the first value `SOCIETE` , `ETABLISSEMENT` , `DEPOT` , `GRP` , `ARTICLE`

For example for table `SOCIETE`  two columns would be created with values `(SSY , Societe SSY)`

Comment: What defines the field type for each new field? What have you tried so far? I'm not sure this is possible without some intermediary code (i.e. PHP, Python, Node, etc) to parse the row and generate/execute another SQL query. At the end of this, what columns would tables `ARTICLE` and `SOCIETE` contain - they're duplicate rows in `data` so it's unclear how they should be generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create the tables as needed:

```
create table societe (ssy ..., societe_ssy ...);
create table etablissement (...);
```

Then you can use `split_part` extract the columns from each string in the source table:

```
insert into societe (ssy, societe_ssy)
select split_part(data, ';', 2),
       split_part(data, ';', 3)
from datasetfact
where data like 'SOCIETE%';

create table etablissement (...)

insert into etablissement (...)
select split_part(data, ';', 2),
       split_part(data, ';', 3),
       split_part(data, ';', 4)
from datasetfact
where data like 'ETABLISSEMENT%';
```